# Using Ionic Calendar for PWA's

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification, progressive-web-apps, ionic4

I'm new to Ionic (and web apps in general) and I'm looking to grab a list of events and display them in a progressive web app (pwa). I looked into Ionic Calendar and some of the other Cordova-Phonegap plugins that allow you to add events to a devices native calendar, but it seems to be unclear whether or not this is for Ionic Native apps or if you can do this with a pwa as well. If this isn't possible with pwa, do I still need to use Calendar to display a list of events and push notifications for upcoming events based on date and time from the app? I appreciate any help in advance. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Ionic Framework to build Hybrid Mobile Apps (requires Cordova/PhoneGap) or PWA's (i.e., Cordova/PhoneGap not required).

N.B. Ionic Native is a suite of TypeScript wrappers for popular Cordova/PhoneGap plugins.

Re "What can a PWA do", see: https://whatwebcando.today/